# HTTP request with SSL 128 bits

Tags: node.js, ssl, request

Working on a webapp using Ogone Direct Paiment, a code working for an old account is working but giving me same error for the new one.

I've added the call made and the answer, maybe someone is used to Ogone API.

The error seems to tell me I have to make a SSL 128bit call but I have no idea how to do that. I've tried lot of things, including `userAgent`, generate certificate myself with `openssl` command but without result.

- If you're familiar with Ogone, let me know how to fix it or how to change the configuration to allow simple queries.
- Otherwise, could you explain me how to make a SSL 128 bit call with nodeJS module `request`?

**Request call**

```
const request= require('request');
const datas = {
    url : 'https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/prod/orderdirect_utf8.asp',
    method:"POST",
    form: 'queryUrlEncoded',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
};

request(datas, (err, response, body) => {
    err && console.error(err);
    body && console.log(body);
});
```

**Response received**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ncresponse [...] NCSTATUS="5" NCERROR="50001115" NCERRORPLUS="SSL 128 required">
</ncresponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module you are using has feature to apply SSL but for that you would need a certificate with key, long story short, yes it is possible.

```
const fs = require('fs')
    , path = require('path')
    , certFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/client.crt')
    , keyFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/client.key')
    , caFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/ca.cert.pem')
    , request = require('request');

const options = {
    url: 'https://api.some-server.com/',
    cert: fs.readFileSync(certFile),
    key: fs.readFileSync(keyFile),
    passphrase: 'password',
    ca: fs.readFileSync(caFile)
};

request.get(options);
```

Copied from documentation.

[Click Here for Documentation](https://github.com/request/request#tlsssl-protocol)

Comment: I've tried it, with local issuer and real certificate but still has the probleme. Maybe it come from Ogone. Can't wait for support answer. BTW thank you for confirming.